# Migration of existing folder/file structure to Plone using funnelweb

Tags: python, plone, plone-funnelweb

I wish to migrate the **existing files and the folder structure** from my PC  irrespective of OS i.e Windows/Linux to Plone 4.1.

I have gone through the document regarding Mr.migrator, transmogrifier, Enfold desktop, FTP etc. But I wish to have a **batch process**, which will walk through the folder structure and create the same with the files in it and upload to Plone **without any intervention**. The file structure should be the same as specified initially, as the server path. Aim is to upload legacy content into Plone before uploading new files and further customizing it to suit the requirement.

Does such a product exist, which can be directly used in buildout.cfg?

Part of the snippet of buildout.cfg now using funnelweb for plone 4.1, on linux debian

```
parts =
    instance
    zopepy
    zopeskel
    unifiedinstaller
    repozo
    backup
    chown
    funnelweb

[funnelweb]
recipe = funnelweb
crawler-site_url=file:///home/xyz/Desktop/MassMail/mm_files 
ploneupload-target=http://admin:admin@localhost:8081/VAGroup
```

The files from the  url need to be uploaded into a plone instance in the folder `/mysore`. If

```
url=file:///home/xyz/Desktop/MassMail/mm_files
```

is used instead of the web page, the files from the folder MassMail from my local system should automatically get uploaded into the VAGroup site at the target folder specified?

How exactly should it be done? Files can contain .doc, .xls, .img, .png, .pdf etc which need to be uploaded to the site. I see all the files in the /var/funnelwebcache/ and also the files with the file.metadata. Why does it not get uploaded into the site? Do I have to specify something else. Also I needed only the files from the folder: `mm_files` not from the parent/grandparent i.e NOT from `home/xyz/Desktop/MassMail` subdirectories which I see in the cache.

Comment: @simahawk, it should be a batch upload without asking any questions pertaining to file size, type of file etc. just upload

Comment: `mr.migrator` does just that, did you have a specific problem with it?

Comment: Please review [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) and insert your configuration file as text, not an image; it's very hard to read this way.

Comment: For one, you won't need the `transmogrify.sqlalchemy` lines as you are not using an external database blueprint anywhere. What does `bin/mr.migrator --show-pipeline` give you? Does that work at all?

Comment: What is the output when you run bin/funnelweb ?

Comment: @djay some bugs after crawling thru' the FS/site and caching the files in funnelwebcache, ..... mr.migrator.runner.runner({'ploneupload': {'target': 'http://admin:admin@localhost:8081/VAGroup/mysore'}, 'crawler': {'site_url':'file:///home/xyz/Desktop/MassMail/mm_files'}},"funnelweb.remote")
 ....Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/transmogrify.ploneremote-1.2-py2.6.egg/transmogrify/ploneremote/remoteconstructor.py", line 83, in __iter__
    _,_,oldpath,_,_,_ = urlparse(f.geturl())
NameError: global name 'urlparse' is not defined    and some other bugs also.

Comment: you should add bugs here https://github.com/collective/transmogrify.ploneremote/issues

Comment: also the current release has bugs in. You'll need checkout the latest versions from github

Comment: @djay which is the release which is fully functional? I have used funnelweb 1.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Zope's built-in FTP and/or WebDAV services to allow intervention-free batch upload of many kinds of files + folders into Plone.  This works extremely well with images, PDFs, Office docs, plain HTML files, etc.  http://plone.org/documentation/kb/webdav/ is a good starting point.  (FTP works very similarly.)    Enfold Desktop provides a friendly Windows front-end to this. (http://www.enfoldsystems.com/news/enfold-desktop-windows-7-plone-4-compatibility)

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is a confusion is between mr.migrator, transmogrifier and funnelweb.

Mr.migrator is a way to run a transmogrifier pipeline via the commandline. Funnelweb is a pre-packaged pipeline.

So if you are using mr.migrator as you are above you need to create a complete transmogrifier pipeline.cfg configuring all the parts yourself.

If you are using funnelweb when you can follow the instructions here https://github.com/collective/funnelweb and use the file url e.g. url=file:///home/xyz/Desktop/MassMail/mm_files and it should work.

Comment: I was just about to put `funnelweb` into a comment. :-) Thanks for answering yourself, Dylan!

Comment: @djay I have reedited my question with funnelweb, if you can guide, Thx in advance